# Can a symmetric matrix become non-symmetric by changing the basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, hermitian-matrices

We know that a hermitian matrix is a matrix which satisfies $A=A^*$, where $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose. A symmetric matrix (special case of hermitian - with real entries) is one for which $A=A^T$.

*Observation:* **this property is dependent on choice of basis.**

We know that we can even choose a basis where these matrices are diagonal (spectral theorem). So, my question is:

1. Is this observation correct?
2. Can we choose a basis where such matrices are not hermitian  or symmetric?
3. If so, is there a characterization of operators whose matrices can be hermitian or symmetric in some basis?

The following is a paragraph from wiki page which I'm unable to understand. Can someone shed light on this?

> ... Denote by $ \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle $ the standard inner product on $R^n$. The real $n-by-n$ matrix $A$ is symmetric if and only if
>
> $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x, Ay\rangle \quad \forall x,y\in\Bbb{R}^n$. Since this definition is independent of the choice of basis, symmetry is a property that depends only on the linear operator A and a choice of inner product. This characterization of symmetry is useful, for example, in differential geometry, for each tangent space to a manifold may be endowed with an inner product, giving rise to what is called a Riemannian manifold. Another area where this formulation is used is in Hilbert spaces...

Comment: The inner product also depends on a choice of basis, up to a unitary transformation.

Comment: I guess that there is some missunderstanding. One has to distinguish between matrices and linear transformations (operators). If one talks about ${\mathbb R}^n$ without mentioning of basis it is understood that we have standard basis and a matrix is then meant to present a linear transformation with respect to the standard basis. So, if we talk about properties of matrices, then they are meant to present a map with respect to the standard bases. If one changes bases the same linear transformation is presented with another matrix (which is similar to the previous one, of course).

Comment: @JankoBracic So, if we say a matrix is symmetric, clearly it is wrt a given basis. So, by changing the basis, can we make it not symmetric ? But wiki saya that symmetry is independent of the basis and is a property of the linear operator and the inner product we are using. since the inner product doesn't change with basis (by a unitary transformation ), the symmetry will be retained with changing the basis(by a unitary transformation ).

Comment: I wanted to point out that matrix, say $T$, is not the same as the linear transformation, say $\tau$. If we talk about a matrix, and we think about the linear transformation which it presents, then we have some fixed bases. If we change bases, then $\tau$ will be presented by some other matrix and also matrix $T$ will present some other transformation. Example, calculate matrices for rotation of angle $\pi/2$ with respect to bases $\vec{i},\vec{j}$ and $\vec{e}=\vec{i}, \vec{f}=\vec{i}+\vec{j}$. Once you will get a symmetric matrix but once... :)

Comment: @JankoBracic I'm not sure what prevents nilpotents from being represented as symmetric matrices? I know that $A^k=0$. So,if $A$ is symmetric why is this not possible ?

Comment: I think you meant to put that comment somewhere else, Srinivas. The point is that if $A$ is not diagonalizable, for example if $A=\pmatrix{0&1\cr0&0\cr}$, then it can't be similar to a symmetric matrix, since you can diagonalize a symmetric matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inner products also depend on a choice of basis. They are invariant under a unitary change of basis, and indeed Hermitian matrices stay Hermitian under unitary change of basis since $(UAU^*)^* = UA^*U^* = UAU^*$.

Comment: Is change of basis possible only by unitary matrices ?

Comment: Certainly not. But the inner product is invariant only under some changes of basis.

Comment: So, by the defn in wiki, we are saying that since the inner product doesn't change ( depending on the basis ), the matrix will remain symmetric in any basis ?

Comment: It won't remain symmetric in any basis – only in a unitary basis. In the same way, the inner product won't remain the same under any basis – only in a unitary basis.

Comment: I'm not sure about this concept of unitary basis. Can you please explain further ?

Comment: It's more usually known as an orthonormal basis. A basis is orthonormal if the change-of-basis matrix is unitary.

Comment: Here, $(UAU^*)^* = UA^*U^* = UAU^*$, where have you specifically used the fact that $U$ is unitary ?

Comment: Usually when you change basis the new matrix has the form $UAU^{-1}$. Unitary matrices satisfy $U^{-1} = U^*$.

Answer (score 12):

The matrices $\pmatrix{1&3\cr0&2\cr}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&2\cr}$ are similar, so there is a change of basis that transforms one into the other, but one is symmetric and the other is not, so, yes, there are transformations that have a symmetric matrix with respect to one basis and not to another basis.

Comment: Is the change of basis matrix orthonormal ? bcoz' i learnt that under orthonormal change of basis we have the symmetry maintained.

Comment: No. An orthonormal change of basis will preserve symmetry.

Comment: I'm also curious to know if given an arbitrary linear transformation, can we find a basis in which it is represented by a symmetric matrix ?

Comment: No, think about non-zero nilpotents.

Answer (score 0):

A Hermitian matrix stays Hermitian only under a unitary transformation.
If $A$ is Hermitian, then $A=A^*$.
Under a unitary transformation,
$B = UAU^*$. Now, $B^* = (UAU^*)^* = U^{**}A^*U^* = UAU^* = B$. Thus, proven.
But if the transformation is non-unitary, then,
$C=WAW^{-1}$. Then, $C^*= (WAW^{-1})^* = (W^{-1})^*AW^* \neq C$, the transformed matrix is not Hermitian.
This is also proved by contradiction, for example, normal matrices have an eigenvalue decomposition, which is essentially a change of basis to have a diagonal representation(which is Hermitian). But normal matrices need not necessarily be Hermitian for this to be true. So, a Hermitian matrix(in this example a diagonal matrix) under a change of basis need not always be Hermitian(a non-Hermitian normal matrix). However, in the case of a Hermitian matrix, the transformation is unitary.